# How can I add this api to wordpress to work automatic?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, api

Guys I want to add shorted links from ouo .io to my wordpress site. I woudl like to use their API:

> You can also use our simple API to shorten your link. The below link
>   will generate a new shorten link and print out in a blank page, it is
>   very easy to inject this API to your application.

```
http://ouo.io/api/WYTlzR4X?s=yourdestinationlink.com
```

I am adding links by additional filed (op1) in post:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_sub_field('op1'); ?>" rel='nofollow' target="_blank" class="prv">
```

I want to get that link shorted, because now I use it like:

```
<a href="http://ouo.io/s/WYTlzR4X?s=<?php echo get_sub_field('op1'); ?>" rel='nofollow' target="_blank" class="prawyklik">
```

what I get is:

```
http://ouo.io/s/WYTlzR4X?s=https://link-added-to-op1.com
```

and I want it to be:

```
http://ouo.io/39pkesT
```

I want to hide real links and show shorted. Please tell me how can I do it to work this way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add to Chay22's answer, you should probably leverage transients so you're not constantly sending the same requests to the URL shortener API.

```
// Get our sub field and create an md5 hash
$sub = get_sub_field('op1');
$md5 = md5( $sub );

// Check if the url has been shortened before, if it hasn't...
if ( false === ( $url = get_transient( 'short-' . $md5 ))) {

    // Grab the shortened url and save the transient for future use
    $url = file_get_contents( 'http://ouo.io/s/WYTlzR4X?s=' . $sub )
    set_transient( 'short-'. $md5, $url );
}

<a href="<?= $url ?>" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" class="prawyklik">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that this can be done with [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
file_get_contents('http://ouo.io/s/WYTlzR4X?s=https://link-added-to-op1.com');
```

So it should be like this

```
<a href="<?php echo file_get_contents('http://ouo.io/s/WYTlzR4X?s='.get_sub_field('op1')); ?>" rel='nofollow' target="_blank" class="prawyklik">
```